# Getting uncommon elements from two columns from two files

Tags: r, subset, intersection

I have two  files for normal and cancer for T cell blood cell sequence like below for cancer

```
> head(cancer[1:2,])
  cloneId cloneCount cloneFraction                         targetSequences
1       0         64    0.02273535 TGCGCATCATGGGATAGCAGCCTGAAAATTGTCCTTTTC
2       1         64    0.02273535       TGTCAACACAGTTACTCTATTCCGTGGACGTTC
                          targetQualities                  allVHitsWithScore
1 EEEEEEENNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN                 IGLV1-51*00(117.6)
2       NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN IGKV1-39*00(152),IGKV1D-39*00(152)
  allDHitsWithScore             allJHitsWithScore             allCHitsWithScore
1                   IGLJ2*00(42.3),IGLJ3*00(42.3) IGLC3*00(118),IGLC2*00(117.3)
2                                  IGKJ1*00(65.4)                   IGKC*00(75)
                                             allVAlignments allDAlignments
1                        421|446|473|0|25|SG425CSA427T|93.0               
2 427|442|471|0|15|SG435C|59.0;349|364|395|0|15|SG357C|59.0               
                             allJAlignments allCAlignments nSeqFR1 minQualFR1
1 27|30|58|36|39||15.0;27|30|58|36|39||15.0              ;      NA         NA
2                      19|30|58|22|33||55.0                     NA         NA
  nSeqCDR1 minQualCDR1 nSeqFR2 minQualFR2 nSeqCDR2 minQualCDR2 nSeqFR3 minQualFR3
1       NA          NA      NA         NA       NA          NA      NA         NA
2       NA          NA      NA         NA       NA          NA      NA         NA
                                 nSeqCDR3 minQualCDR3 nSeqFR4 minQualFR4 aaSeqFR1
1 TGCGCATCATGGGATAGCAGCCTGAAAATTGTCCTTTTC          36      NA         NA       NA
2       TGTCAACACAGTTACTCTATTCCGTGGACGTTC          45      NA         NA       NA
  aaSeqCDR1 aaSeqFR2 aaSeqCDR2 aaSeqFR3     aaSeqCDR3 aaSeqFR4
1        NA       NA        NA       NA CASWDSSLKIVLF       NA
2        NA       NA        NA       NA   CQHSYSIPWTF       NA
                         refPoints
1 :::::::::0:-7:25:::::36:-7:39:::
2  :::::::::0:-9:15:::::22:1:33:::
> names(cancer)
 [1] "cloneId"           "cloneCount"        "cloneFraction"     "targetSequences"  
 [5] "targetQualities"   "allVHitsWithScore" "allDHitsWithScore" "allJHitsWithScore"
 [9] "allCHitsWithScore" "allVAlignments"    "allDAlignments"    "allJAlignments"   
[13] "allCAlignments"    "nSeqFR1"           "minQualFR1"        "nSeqCDR1"         
[17] "minQualCDR1"       "nSeqFR2"           "minQualFR2"        "nSeqCDR2"         
[21] "minQualCDR2"       "nSeqFR3"           "minQualFR3"        "nSeqCDR3"         
[25] "minQualCDR3"       "nSeqFR4"           "minQualFR4"        "aaSeqFR1"         
[29] "aaSeqCDR1"         "aaSeqFR2"          "aaSeqCDR2"         "aaSeqFR3"         
[33] "aaSeqCDR3"         "aaSeqFR4"          "refPoints"        
>
```

And for normal

```
> head(normal[1:2,])
  cloneId cloneCount cloneFraction                         targetSequences
1       0        100    0.03745318 TGCGCATCATGGGATAGCAGCCTGAAAATTGTCCTTTTC
2       1         53    0.01985019       TGTCAACACAGTTACTCTATTCCGTGGACGTTC
                          targetQualities                      allVHitsWithScore
1 EEEENNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN                     IGLV1-51*00(115.8)
2       NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNEEEE IGKV1-39*00(124.4),IGKV1D-39*00(124.4)
  allDHitsWithScore             allJHitsWithScore               allCHitsWithScore
1                   IGLJ2*00(44.8),IGLJ3*00(44.8) IGLC2*00(103.3),IGLC3*00(103.3)
2                                  IGKJ1*00(61.2)                  IGKC*00(114.2)
                                             allVAlignments allDAlignments
1                        421|446|473|0|25|SG425CSA427T|93.0               
2 427|442|471|0|15|SG435C|59.0;349|364|395|0|15|SG357C|59.0               
                             allJAlignments allCAlignments nSeqFR1 minQualFR1
1 27|30|58|36|39||15.0;27|30|58|36|39||15.0              ;      NA         NA
2                      19|30|58|22|33||55.0                     NA         NA
  nSeqCDR1 minQualCDR1 nSeqFR2 minQualFR2 nSeqCDR2 minQualCDR2 nSeqFR3 minQualFR3
1       NA          NA      NA         NA       NA          NA      NA         NA
2       NA          NA      NA         NA       NA          NA      NA         NA
                                 nSeqCDR3 minQualCDR3 nSeqFR4 minQualFR4 aaSeqFR1
1 TGCGCATCATGGGATAGCAGCCTGAAAATTGTCCTTTTC          36      NA         NA       NA
2       TGTCAACACAGTTACTCTATTCCGTGGACGTTC          36      NA         NA       NA
  aaSeqCDR1 aaSeqFR2 aaSeqCDR2 aaSeqFR3     aaSeqCDR3 aaSeqFR4
1        NA       NA        NA       NA CASWDSSLKIVLF       NA
2        NA       NA        NA       NA   CQHSYSIPWTF       NA
                         refPoints
1 :::::::::0:-7:25:::::36:-7:39:::
2  :::::::::0:-9:15:::::22:1:33:::
>
```

How I can get subset the cancer file for uncommon elements in `aaSeqCDR3` and `nSeqCDR3` columns?

I mean I have cancer file in these two columns all elements are unique and not common with normal file

Comment: Thank you the output wouldbe similar with the data frame attached here but elements in these two columns are unique. I have attached header of normal file too and a screen shot when with venny I am looking at commonlity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to subset based on elements that are not present in 'normal', use `anti_join`

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(cancer, normal[ c("aaSeqCDR3", "nSeqCDR3")],
          by = c("aaSeqCDR3", "nSeqCDR3"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much when I use venn diagram I see 1627 unique in cancer but by your kindly code I see 2700 unique